# How to make a range of numbers for 31 days containing 744 hours

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have 744 data as y-axis that I want to plot with a month as x-axis which contains 31 days (or equals to 744 hours). How can I create a list of 31 days that contain 744 of data's precisely, so I can plot it with y-values? (which has to have the same length of numbers for plotting)

I've tried to divided 31/744 but it didn't have the same length as y-values

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 


plt.figure(figsize = (8, 5))

x = np.arange(0, 31, (0.04005167))
y = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/user/Documents/project/Data/Data-y.xlsx')

plt.plot(x, y, 'b')
plt.show()
```

I expect the graphs will show 31 days in x-axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `np.arange(0, 31, (0.04005167))` and manually calculate the steps.

Numpy has [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html), which according to the docs,

> Return evenly spaced numbers over a specified interval.
>   Returns num evenly spaced samples, calculated over the interval
>   [start, stop].
>
> The endpoint of the interval can optionally be excluded.

Hence, simply

```
np.linspace(0, 31, 744)
```

will do